# Tensorflow Time Series Tutorial: error using a large data window

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series

I'm following the [tensorflow time series tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) with my own data.
After feature engineering, my df has 117 rows × 8 columns.
I do data splitting and normalizing exactly the same as the tutorial.
All the code for data windowing, other functions & models is exactly the same, except that I have a different target variable

I define the wide_window exactly as described in the tutorial:

```
wide_window = WindowGenerator(
    input_width=24, label_width=24, shift=1,
    label_columns=[target])
```

Running the models up until the LSTM model works fine.

**Problem:**
However, running

```
lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
history = compile_and_fit(lstm_model, wide_window)
IPython.display.clear_output()
val_performance['LSTM'] = lstm_model.evaluate(wide_window.val) # ERROR
performance['LSTM'] = lstm_model.evaluate(wide_window.test, verbose=0) # ERROR
```

throws the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in update(self, current, values, finalize)
    921 
    922       if self.target is not None:
--> 923         numdigits = int(np.log10(self.target)) + 1
    924         bar = ('%' + str(numdigits) + 'd/%d [') % (current, self.target)
    925         prog = float(current) / self.target

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

**What I figured out:**
If I reduce the input_width and label_width of the wide_window to <12, this model and the following multi-output models work fine.
With a bigger window, the single-output lstm and all the multi-output models throw this error.

**Question:**
Why can I only have such a small window?

Comment: what is your target variable @amy989 and without a data sample and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's impossible to help you

Comment: I can't post all my data. my variables are numerical values just like in the tutorial, and they're normalized so they have similar value ranges.

Comment: Use gist etc. Never ALL data! We need a MINIMAL reproducible example. Read the link I posted above about it. Cannot answer without knowing.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't notice Warning above the ValueError

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:915:
> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10   numdigits =
> int(np.log10(self.target)) + 1

and you've got your data "**117 rows × 8 columns**"

first and foremost CHECK your data's shapes (as in tutorial)

```
print('Input shape:', wide_window.example[0].shape)
print('Output shape:', lstm_model(wide_window.example[0]).shape)
```

where it shows

> Input shape: (32, 24, 19) Output shape: (32, 24, 1)

but your data should give *[batch_size, **NUM_TIMESTEPS**, num_columns=8]* as input. But when you split your 117 rows to *train, val, test df's* at the beginning

```
n = len(df)
train_df = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = df[int(n*0.9):]
```

e.g. *test_df* you get ONLY ~ 11.7 and for val_df ONLY ~23.4 records that is SMALLER then *input_width=24, label_width=24* given in *WindowGenerator* (24!) that should become your timesteps_for_backpropagation. You should assign timesteps in WindowGenerator LESS then you have data rows in EVERY split - in order to make at least 1 rolling step-forward in timeseries for the opportunity to backpropagate without any *division by 0* in tf_lib -- when fitting the model for both train_df & val.df

ALWAYS check shapes! (in model & your data)

**To your Question:** concerning *train_df* 117/24~4,8 seq qty of iteration... And, increasing your *window_size* - you will get less less iteration steps while propagating error backward